# Draw line that goes under node TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a directed graph in which I want to draw vertical lines like the three red ones added here by hand:

[image]

Each section represents a time period. The annotations `e1` and `v1` name the adjacent nodes. They do not need to appear in the output.

I tried using

`\draw[dotted] ([yshift=-1.9cm]e1.south) -- ([yshift=0.5cm]v1.north)`

where `e1` and `v1` are the marked nodes, with similar statements for the other  two pairs of nodes, and inserted all three statements at the end of the code.

```
%Preamble
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
% Original graph starts here
\begin{tikzpicture}[label/.style = {draw, fill=white, ellipse, scale=0.8, inner sep=0.07cm, minimum height=0.6cm, minimum width=1cm},
                    node/.style = {minimum height=0.6cm, minimum width=1cm},
                    s>/.style = {->,out=90,in=210,looseness=1.5, dotted}]
%Nodes:
\node[draw] (vt-1) {$\tilde{V}_{it-1}$}; 
\node[draw] (st-1) [right = 1.6cm of vt-1, node] {$S_{it-1}$};
\node[draw] (st)   [right = 2.4cm of st-1, node] {$S_{it}$};
\node[draw] (it)   [below = 2.2cm of st  , node] {$\tilde{I}_{it}$};
\node[draw] (st+1) [right = 2.4cm of st  , node] {$S_{it+1}$};
\node[draw] (it+1) [below = 2.2cm of st+1, node] {$\tilde{I}_{it+1}$};
\node (st+2) [right = 2.4cm of st+1, node] {...};
\node (it+2) [below = 2.2cm of st+2, node] {...};

%Lines from t-1 -> t
\draw[->] (vt-1) to node[label](v0){$-1$} (st-1);
\draw[->] (st-1) to node[label](v1){$-1$} (st);
\draw[->] (st-1) to node[label](e1){$-e(t-1)$} (it);

%Lines from t -> t+1
\draw[->] (st)   to node[label](v2){$-1$} (st+1);
\draw[->] (st)   to node[label](e2){$-e(t)$} (it+1);
\draw[s>] (it)   to node[label, pos=0.2]{$e(t-1)$} (st+1);
\draw[->] (it)   to (e2);

%Lines from t+1 -> \infty
\draw[->] (st+1)   to node[label](v3){$-1$}(st+2);
\draw[->] (st+1)   to node[label](e3){$-e(t+1)$} (it+2);
\draw[s>] (it+1)   to node[label, pos=0.2]{$e(t)$} (st+2);
\draw[->] (it+1)   to (e3);

%Text with t-1, t, ...
\node [above = 0.2cm of v0] {$t-1$};
\node [above = 0.2cm of st] {$t$};
\node [above = 0.2cm of st+1] {$t+1$};
\node [above = 0.2cm of st+2] {$t \rightarrow \infty$};
%Original graph ends here

%Added lines:
\draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1.9cm]e1.south) -- ([yshift=0.5cm]v1.north);
\draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1.9cm]e2.south) -- ([yshift=0.5cm]v2.north);
\draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1.9cm]e3.south) -- ([yshift=0.5cm]v3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This gave the following:

[image]

But I wanted the lines to be behind the nodes.

I imagine one could draw a line from `e1.south` to the southern end of the graph, another from `e1.north` to `v1.south`, and a third one from `e1.north` to the northern end of the graph ( likewise for the rest of the pairs). But: (i) it seems there should be a better solution, and (ii) I don't know how to draw a line from a node to a  point with no node. Observation: by "northern end of the graph", I mean a point with same x coord. and +0.5cm y coord.

Comment: Please provide a complete LaTeX code, so that we can know which packages you load and which TikZ library you're using.

Comment: Sorry, done! @Miyase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the Background library of Tikz, which is described in the manual.  I added that library to the list you already  had in the `\usetikzlibrary` argument list and modified the last few lines of your code to put the vertical lines in the background.  The result follows.

```
%Preamble
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.geometric, backgrounds}

\begin{document}
% Original graph starts here
\begin{tikzpicture}[label/.style = {draw, fill=white, ellipse, scale=0.8, inner sep=0.07cm, minimum height=0.6cm, minimum width=1cm},
                    node/.style = {minimum height=0.6cm, minimum width=1cm},
                    s>/.style = {->,out=90,in=210,looseness=1.5, dotted}]
%Nodes:
\node[draw] (vt-1) {$\tilde{V}_{it-1}$}; 
\node[draw] (st-1) [right = 1.6cm of vt-1, node] {$S_{it-1}$};
\node[draw] (st)   [right = 2.4cm of st-1, node] {$S_{it}$};
\node[draw] (it)   [below = 2.2cm of st  , node] {$\tilde{I}_{it}$};
\node[draw] (st+1) [right = 2.4cm of st  , node] {$S_{it+1}$};
\node[draw] (it+1) [below = 2.2cm of st+1, node] {$\tilde{I}_{it+1}$};
\node (st+2) [right = 2.4cm of st+1, node] {...};
\node (it+2) [below = 2.2cm of st+2, node] {...};

%Lines from t-1 -> t
\draw[->] (vt-1) to node[label](v0){$-1$} (st-1);
\draw[->] (st-1) to node[label](v1){$-1$} (st);
\draw[->] (st-1) to node[label](e1){$-e(t-1)$} (it);

%Lines from t -> t+1
\draw[->] (st)   to node[label](v2){$-1$} (st+1);
\draw[->] (st)   to node[label](e2){$-e(t)$} (it+1);
\draw[s>] (it)   to node[label, pos=0.2]{$e(t-1)$} (st+1);
\draw[->] (it)   to (e2);

%Lines from t+1 -> \infty
\draw[->] (st+1)   to node[label](v3){$-1$}(st+2);
\draw[->] (st+1)   to node[label](e3){$-e(t+1)$} (it+2);
\draw[s>] (it+1)   to node[label, pos=0.2]{$e(t)$} (st+2);
\draw[->] (it+1)   to (e3);

%Text with t-1, t, ...
\node [above = 0.2cm of v0] {$t-1$};
\node [above = 0.2cm of st] {$t$};
\node [above = 0.2cm of st+1] {$t+1$};
\node [above = 0.2cm of st+2] {$t \rightarrow \infty$};
%Original graph ends here

%Added lines:
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
  \draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1.9cm]e1.south) -- ([yshift=0.5cm]v1.north);
  \draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1.9cm]e2.south) -- ([yshift=0.5cm]v2.north);
  \draw[dashed] ([yshift=-1.9cm]e3.south) -- ([yshift=0.5cm]v3.north);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some off-topics remarks and sugestion (since problem is already solved by other answer):

- To my opinion is not good idea use style names, which are used in `\tikz` commands: `\node` or `node` and `label`. This can be error prone ... Better is for example select `N` for `node` and `L` for `label`. They can be easy to distinguee from commands of the same name and are also much shorter.
- your image is wider than default `\textwidth` of `article` package. Using `scale` in nodes styles definition is not good solution, better is:

  - define smaller fonts and horizontal node distance, for example `\footnotesize` and `node distance = 22mm and 19mm` respectively; or
  - increase `\textwidth` of document by employ `geometry` package
- With use of `chains` library and `\foreach` loops for positioning of nodes, your image code can be much shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                chains,
                positioning, 
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \footnotesize
% Original graph starts here
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
            > = Straight Barb,
node distance = 22mm and 24mm,
  start chain = going right,
     L/.style = {ellipse, draw, fill=white, 
                 inner xsep=#1, inner ysep=2pt},
     L/.default = 1pt,
     N/.style = {draw, minimum width=3em},
    s>/.style = {->, out=90, in=195, looseness=1.2, dotted}
                        ]
% nodes in chain:
    \foreach \i [count=\j] in {\tilde{V}_{it-1}, S_{it-1}, S_{it}, S_{it+1}, \dotsm}
{
\ifnum\j<5    
    \node (s\j) [N, on chain, join=by ->] {$\i$};
\else
    \node (s\j) [on chain, join=by ->] {$\i$};
\fi
}
% nodes "-1" in chain
    \foreach \i [count=\j from 2] in {1,2,3,4}
\path (s\i) -- node (h\i) [L] {$-1$} (s\j);
% nodes at top
\node   [above=5mm] at (h1)   {$t-1$};
\node   [above=5mm] at (s3)   {$t$};
\node   [above=5mm] at (s4)   {$t+1$};
\node   [above=5mm] at (s5)   {$t\to\infty$};
% nodes at bottom
\node (i1) [N, below = of s3]   {$\tilde{I}_{it}$};
\node (i2) [N, below = of s4]   {$\tilde{I}_{it+1}$};
\node (i3) [below = of s5]      {$\dotsm$};
% diagonal lines with nodes
\draw[->] (s2) -- node (e1) [L=-3pt] {$-e(t-1)$} (i1);
\draw[->] (s3) -- node (e2) [L]      {$-e(t)$}   (i2);
\draw[->] (s4) -- node (e3) [L=-3pt] {$-e(t+1)$} (i3);
%
\draw[->] (i1) -- (e2);
\draw[->] (i2) -- (e3);
% dotted curved lines
\draw[s>] (i1) to node[L=-3, pos=0.3]{$e(t-1)$} (s4.200);
\draw[s>] (i2) to node[L, pos=0.3]{$e(t)$} (s5.200);
%
% vertical dashed lines:
\scoped[on background layer]
{
\foreach \x in {2,3,4} 
  \draw[dashed] ([yshift=5mm] h\x.north) -- ([yshift=-5mm] h\x |- i1.south);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows text borders)